# Centering headers

Tags: sectioning

What are the ways to center headers only without using the titlesec and sectsty packages?
If we take the titlesec package, then the question is how to prevent this package from automatically changing header styles?

Comment: that depends what you want to change, section headings are defined by the document class, so any answer  will depend on the class you are using

Comment: ncc document class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ncc` class has its own method.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{ncc}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\TitleBeforeAuthor

\sectionstyle{center}
\indentaftersection

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Pavel}

\maketitle

\section{Centered title}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\subsection{Centered title}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `\indentaftersection` if you don't want the first paragraph after a title to be indented.

Comment: The string \usepackage[headers]{ncchdr} is optional, centering works without this package

Comment: @Pavel You're right, I forgot to remove it.